# v-row and v-col not placing two items in same row in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a form where a button and a toggle are on same line. I have this code.

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <codemirror v-model="code" ref="myCm" :options="cmOptions"></codemirror>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
            <v-btn v-if="isQueryNotInProgress" v-on:click="onSubmit">Submit</v-btn>
            <v-progress-circular v-if="!isQueryNotInProgress" indeterminate/>
            <v-btn v-if="!isQueryNotInProgress" v-on:click="cancelQuery">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-switch v-model="cacheSwitch" :label="`Ignore Cache`"></v-switch>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

But the elements are coming vertically instead of being arranged side by side. I want the submit button and ignore cache buttons side by side instead.

[image]

I have also tried setting them in multiple columns as shown below. But they are still one over the other. I've also tried setting `cols="6"` for both the columns, without any luck. Can someone help me display these side by side?

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <codemirror v-model="code" ref="myCm" :options="cmOptions"></codemirror>
        </v-row>
        <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <v-btn v-if="isQueryNotInProgress" v-on:click="onSubmit">Submit</v-btn>
                <v-progress-circular v-if="!isQueryNotInProgress" indeterminate/>
                <v-btn v-if="!isQueryNotInProgress" v-on:click="cancelQuery">Cancel</v-btn>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>
                <v-switch v-model="cacheSwitch" :label="`Ignore Cache`"></v-switch>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: Works as attended: https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/bGGbNrV?editors=1011, Only when the container hasn't enough space the cols are displayed under each other

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I added multiple buttons and they are all coming in one line. but when I add v-switch it is being pushed to next line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use  `<v-layout row wrap>` and  `<v-flex>` to get them onto one line. Here is the code.

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm12>
                <codemirror v-model="code" ref="myCm" :options="cmOptions"></codemirror>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex xs12 sm2>
                <v-btn v-if="isQueryNotInProgress" v-on:click="onSubmit">Submit</v-btn>
                <v-progress-circular v-if="!isQueryNotInProgress" indeterminate/>
                <v-btn v-if="!isQueryNotInProgress" v-on:click="cancelQuery">Cancel</v-btn>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm6>
                <v-switch v-model="ignoreCache" :label="`Ignore Cache`"></v-switch>
            </v-flex>
            <v-flex xs12 sm4>
                <v-btn v-on:click="onQuery1Click">Query 1</v-btn>
                <v-btn v-on:click="onQuery2Click">Query 2</v-btn>
                <v-btn v-on:click="onQuery3Click">Query 3</v-btn>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-container>
</template>
```

Here is the end result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<v-row>
 <v-col cols="auto">
  <v-btn>Button 1</v-btn>
  <v-btn>Button 2</v-btn>
  <v-btn>Button 3</v-btn>
 </v-col>
</v-row>
```

And as long as you have enough space you'll be fine.